# SingleBOdy cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, android

i am trying this solution for my application:
[Sending images using Http Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935946/sending-images-using-http-post/15499598#15499598)
.(first answer)
At frist i had problem with eclipse not wanting to import external jars, bat when i solved that problem i got this error:

The type org.apache.james.mime4j.message.SingleBody cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

on lines:

```
entity.addPart(nameValuePairs.get(index).getName(), new FileBody(new File(nameValuePairs.get(index).getValue())));
```

and

```
entity.addPart(nameValuePairs.get(index).getName(), new StringBody(nameValuePairs.get(index).getValue()));
```

any help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067655/how-to-upload-a-file-using-java-httpclient-library-working-with-php-strange-pr

Comment: i was looking at that post, but there is nothing that can help me with this problem...

Comment: Have you seen the second comment of the first answer?

Comment: yes, but i am using httpmime-4.0.1.jar, and in post i was looking at (in post) it is not saying about importing httpClinet or httpCore jars, and they are much biger then this httpmime. So is there a way i can fix this without importing them insted?

Comment: Problem solved. It just started working without any change. i dont know how and i dont know why...

Answer (score 1):

Simple,  The jar file which you are using is wrong file..

Same issue irritate me several times..

Download jar file from  [Grep code](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.james/apache-mime4j/0.6) Which is **Binary Download**

the package name in **Source Download** jar file is not proper like org.apache.james.mime4j_.XXXXXX

and the Packages in **Binary Download** jar file is proper like org.apache.james.mime4j.XXXXXX

Wasted a lot of time on it today :( finally **solved**

Answer (score 0):

Having same problem and download the lib from [here (only)](http://archive.apache.org/dist/james/mime4j/) solve the problem. I did download from other sites somehow they just did not resolved the problem.